# codeigniter library within library issue

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to call libraryA within libraryB in the constructor of the libraryB.
I am aware I can do:

```
$CI =& get_instance();
$CI->load->library('A');
$CI->A->someFunc()
```

However I cannot call `$CI->A->someFunc()` without initiating it with
`$CI =& get_instance();` `$CI->load->library('A');` in whatever function in B I am trying to access `someFunc();`. In other situations I would just be able to initiate it in the constructor `$this->load->model('somemodel');` and call the model in any function within the class with `$this->load->someFunc();`. How to I achieve the same functionality without having to rewrite the block of code above over and over in each function I want to use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% clear this is what you're asking (your question is confusing), but you can save the CI instance as a property, then access it from anywhere in your class.

```
class My_library {

    protected $CI;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->CI =& get_instance();

        $this->CI->load->library('other_library');
    }

    public function someMethod()
    {
        // Use the library (and the CI object) via the CI property.
        $var = $this->CI->other_library->anotherMethod();
    }
}
```

Comment: yea sorry my question was a bit convoluted. this worked like a charm.